# jQuery UI Autocomplete: Strange Behaviour of suggestion list after first number

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I got the following problem with my autocomplete on a textbox: The user can enter a number and gets a list of suggestions like he should. That works but only for the first number, if I hit a 2nd number, the list cuts off some entries and I don't know why.

To describe the problem in more details: 
At the Moment the following numbers are in the database:
123456
123457
123458
123459
1234510
1234511
1234512
1234513
123451

If I type in 1, all 9 entries are in the list as they should. If I type in 12 only these entries are in the list:

123451
123456
123457
123458
123459

The rest is gone and I really don't know why. So I hope you guys can give me an advice or see where my mistake is at:

Here is the code that is used by the view to create the autocomplete feature:

```
<script>
    $("#CompanyId").autocomplete({
        source: "/AutoComplete/AutoCompleteCompanyID",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
        }
    });
</script>
```

The source of data for autocomplete:

```
public JsonResult AutoCompleteCompanyID(string term)
{
    var data = db.Companies.Where(s => s.CompanyID.ToString().Contains(term)).Select(x => new { id = x.CompanyID, label = x.CompanyName }).ToArray();
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If you need any more pieces of code or information so see where the problem is, I will provide it as fast as possible for you. Thanks for any help and advice! :)

Comment: So you mean to say after you type `12` then if you erase and type `1` the 9 entries are not shown back?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The problem has been solved, for more details, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to replicate this but I think it has to do with the conversion of `CompanyID` to a string, you may need to cast db results to an enumerable - e.g.

```
var data = db.Companies.ToList().Where(s => s.CompanyID.ToString().Contains(term)).Select(x => new { id = x.CompanyID, label = x.CompanyName }).ToArray();
```

Aside: It may be easier to run your search off `CompanyName` instead, its a bit much to ask users to remember the IDs of companies to search for.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, the code-snippet and your advice. It's pretty logic that you can't replicate it, because I did something else wrong or at least different. I was using double to store my ID because there were cases where the number was pretty long and I didn't thought of long as a type. So I switched from double to long and now everything works fine.